# How to create a new worksheet in existing Google Sheets file using python and google sheets api?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use an old python code I used about an year ago (in a different account) but now it's not working anymore and I just can't fix it.

```
def create_new_sheet(sheet_name, sheet_id):

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'token.json'
    creds = None
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes = SCOPES)

    SPREADSHEET_ID = sheet_id

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
            
    body = {
        "requests":{
            "addSheet":{
                "properties":{
                    "title":f"{sheet_name}"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId = SPREADSHEET_ID, body = body).execute()
```

I already have the token, and with it I can read data without any problems, but when I try to create a new sheet, this error happens:

`MalformedError: Service account info was not in the expected format, missing fields client_email.`

I'm basically doing the same thing I did in the past but now I'm having this error. Could someone help me understand what's happening here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message that you are getting indicates that you are trying to do this using a service account and the service account key file that you are using called `token.json` does not the have the correct structure.

The way your code will go depends if you want to use OAuth with regular users or a service account.

This is the full code I used for testing with the service account method:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

def create_new_sheet(sheet_name, sheet_id):

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'token.json'
    creds = None
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes = SCOPES)

    SPREADSHEET_ID = sheet_id

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
            
    body = {
        "requests":{
            "addSheet":{
                "properties":{
                    "title":f"{sheet_name}"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId = SPREADSHEET_ID, body = body).execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_new_sheet('Test name', 'Spreadtsheet ID')
```

This is the structure that the service account key file called `token.json` should have:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n
PRIVATE KEY HERE
\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

Based on the error message it looks like you are missing the `client_email` field from the `token.json` file. Make sure to create a new one and download it correctly from the GCP console and try again.

In case you want to do it using OAuth authenticating a regular user that is an editor of the file this is the code that you should use instead:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


def sheets_batch_update(spreadsheet_id, title):
     
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member

    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

        requests = []
        # Change the spreadsheet's title.
        requests.append({
            'addSheet': {
                'properties': {
                    'title': title
                },
            }
        })

        body = {
            'requests': requests
        }
        response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
            body=body).execute()

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sheets_batch_update('Spreadsheet ID', 'Test name')
```

If you use this method make sure to delete your current `token.json` file as the structure for this case will be different.

#### References:

- [Setting up API keys](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862)
- [Update spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate)
- [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests)